# Column separator cut in half

Tags: tables

For some reason, the column for all columns except for the first one are cut in half in each line. Here is the code

```
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$}}
            |v_2| & p_2+\textbf{i}\cdot q_2 & |v_{3}| & q_4  \\
            \hline\\
            1.0300 & -0.4204 + 0.1475i & 0.9400 &  0.5572 \\ \hline \\
            1.0390 & -0.4082 - 0.3263i & 0.9500 &  0.0779 \\ \hline \\
            1.0481 & -0.4122 - 0.7972i & 0.9600 & -0.3905 \\ \hline \\
            1.0571 & -0.4311 - 1.2557i & 0.9700 & -0.8390 
\end{tabular}
```

And here is the resulting table:

[image: table]

It can be clearly seen that something is wrong with the second and third separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have presumably-unwanted line break indicators after all 4 `\hline` statements: Omit them.

If you want a bit more vertical space between rows, consider loading the `array` package and issuing the directive `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`.

Separately, since the entire contents of the table are in math mode, consider using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. And, while in math mode, use `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`.

For a more "open" look, consider getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines; for the horizontal line that divides the header row from the table body, consider using `\midrule` instead of `\hline`

A full MWE (minimum working example) that implements both stylistic ideas:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for "\midrule" macro
\begin{document}

% Solution 1, with vertical lines and four horizontal lines
\begingroup
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional
\[
\begin{array}{c|c|c|r}
            |v_2| & p_2+\mathbf{i}\cdot q_2 & |v_{3}| & \multicolumn{1}{c}{q_4}  \\
            \hline
            1.0300 & -0.4204 + 0.1475i & 0.9400 &  0.5572 \\ \hline
            1.0390 & -0.4082 - 0.3263i & 0.9500 &  0.0779 \\ \hline
            1.0481 & -0.4122 - 0.7972i & 0.9600 & -0.3905 \\ \hline
            1.0571 & -0.4311 - 1.2557i & 0.9700 & -0.8390
\end{array}
\]
\endgroup

% Solution 2, with just 1 horizontal rule 
\[
\begin{array}{@{}cccr@{}}
            |v_2| & p_2+\mathbf{i}\cdot q_2 & |v_{3}| & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{q_4}  \\
            \midrule
            1.0300 & -0.4204 + 0.1475i & 0.9400 &  0.5572 \\
            1.0390 & -0.4082 - 0.3263i & 0.9500 &  0.0779 \\
            1.0481 & -0.4122 - 0.7972i & 0.9600 & -0.3905 \\
            1.0571 & -0.4311 - 1.2557i & 0.9700 & -0.8390
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: adding `\def\arraystretch{2}` turns the row height to twice the height of a "normal" row

Comment: @EladDen - Thanks. Are you mentioning this instruction as a general possibility, or are you recommending it be applied for the table at hand?

Comment: a general possibility, there's always more than one way of doing things, and I did not want to add an answer just for that one line :)